# ¿Cómo leer una lista de nombres y contar las repeticiones?

Tags: c++

Lo del titulo, la funcion deberia leer una lista de nombres (vec2), contar cuantas veces se repite (por ejemplo ana - 5) y mostrar los "n" nombres más repetidos

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

ifstream ent;
ofstream sal;

void Errores (int c, int n);
vector<string> LeerVec(vector<string> vec0, int c);
vector<string> EscribirVec(vector<string> vec2);

int main(){
    //preparo los archivos
    ent.open("nombres.in");
    sal.open("nombres.out");

    //declaro las variables
    int c, n;
    vector<string> A;

    //lectura de los archivos
    ent>>c >>n; 
    A=LeerVec(A, c);
    Errores (c, n);

    //Escribir el vector
    A=EscribirVec(A);

    //MostrarVec(A);

    //cierro los archivos
    ent.close();
    sal.close();

    return 0;
}

//leer el vector
vector<string> LeerVec(vector<string> vec0, int c){
    string palabra;

    for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
        ent>> palabra;
        vec0.push_back(palabra);
    }

    return vec0;
}

//revisar errorres
void Errores (int c, int n){

    if((c<2)||(c>1000)){
        cout<<"[ERROR] La cantidad de chicos debe ser mayor que 2 y menor que 1000 [ERROR]" <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if((n<1)||(n>100)){
        cout<<"[ERROR] La cantidad de nombres mas frecuentes debe ser mayor a 1 y menor a 100 [ERROR]" <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

//escribir el vector
vector<string>EscribirVec(vector<string> vec2){
    vector<int> Nums;
    vector<string> vec3;
    int cont=1;

    sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end()); 

    for(int i=0;i<vec2.size();i++){
        if(vec2[i]==vec2[i+1]){
            cont+=1;
            cout<<"("<<cont<<") "; //PRUEBA
        }

        if(vec2[i]!=vec2[i+1]){
            for(int i=0;i<vec2.size();i++){
                vec3.push_back(vec2[i]); //guarda el  nombre
                Nums.push_back(cont); //guarda el contador
                }
                
            cout<<vec3[i]<<" ["<<Nums[i]<<"] "<<endl; //PRUEBA
            cont=1; // reinicia
        }
    }

    return vec3;
}
```

El archivo "nombres.in" dice:

```
25 3
Ana
Ricardo
Juan
Ester
Juana
Pedro
Federico
Juan
Ismael
Juan
Ana
Pilar
Juan
Ana
Juana
Ana
Ricardo
Juan
Manuel
Juana
Pilar
Juana
Ana
Juan
Juan
```

Nombres.out tendria el top. si quisiera mostrar los 3 nombres más repetidos diría:

```
Ana 5
Juan 7
Juana 4
```

No se me ocurre que es lo que no funciona, la variable "nums" guarda siempre 5 y el último nombre no se muestra.

Answer (score 3):

Para clasificar elementos sin repeticiones, una de las soluciones más comunes es usar un `std::map`, en tu caso necesitarías  un `std::map<std::string, int>` en el que la clave sería el nombre y el valor la cantidad de apariciones.

La función [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) te permite insertar un elemento y te devuelve un iterador al elemento insertado (o al previamente existente si el elemento ya existía), por lo tanto este código:

```
using nombres = std::map<std::string, int>;
nombres n;

auto insercion = n.insert({"ana", 0});
++insercion.first->second;

insercion = n.insert({"ana", 0});
++insercion.first->second;

for (const auto &nombre : n)
    std::cout << nombre.first << " se repite: " << nombre.second << '\n';
```

Produce la siguiente salida:

> ```
> ana se repite: 2
> ```

Puedes generalizar la operación en una función:

```
void cuenta_nombre(nombres &n, const std::string &nombre)
{
    auto insercion = n.insert({nombre, 0});
    ++insercion.first->second;
}
```

El *problema* es que los mapas se ordenan por clave no por valor, así que para obtener el top X deberás dar la vuelta al mapa resultante, puedes usar [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) para esa operación:

```
using nombres = std::map<std::string, int>;
using apariciones = std::map<int, std::string, std::greater<int>>;

nombres n;
// Rellenar nombres
apariciones a;
// Girar los elementos del mapa de nombres:
std::transform(n.begin(), n.end(), std::inserter(a, a.begin()),
    [](const auto &i) { return std::make_pair(i.second, i.first); } );

for (const auto &aparicion : a)
    std::cout << aparicion.second << " aparece " << aparicion.first << " veces\n";
```

Usando el código anterior sobre tu conjunto de datos, la salida es la siguiente:

> ```
> Juan aparece 7 veces
> Ana aparece 5 veces
> Juana aparece 4 veces
> Pilar aparece 2 veces
> Ester aparece 1 veces
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLBatwwED1bXzFsINjEMTnvbhd6aKGBQOi1W8LEnjii9shIcnJY9tu3Y8l27LQXoZl5895onsquuy0b5PpyudJcNn1FsNfGeUvYHtRHTjKa62WmxW4F@LcHm9pY7V8lqXon7cCmfbbk4As4X223QrEPl8ieg2Z/2I1Y7NDqUhte4wWSw6opBLWIe7JD@SAU6s3oCsqe2ONTVE0n8WvOoTTs/JJGsqGcqZNKsPdGZnFkB31R5yJEPj1FVA5352ynkpubGVW8aOv87cGRcFc7dVZKZoEWNaeBdCEWVwXOnTZfGY/8U5doK3Pk@x75yN@cvCQGUnykykrpO1Uk@5hBP1yL1ExRoHnUDdpVZqT4n8gDcj/1r3tx0RzPzVneOq2PZbvLx4ymCuL9VTeURjvIN5olcPlYzzKVyBaST57MZemXlSVL13FW8hbZvRjbplw8Uz2sVBoL4mq4BEg0iGyKOeAEkuKv32k0O5h6rTM4gSXfW57@1B966lDbVBfRO/mG0cxsB2fIhiFEGlY085iwBZSXxTFL03vY7z@@7sg45DYhSyXJbQUJUhHxJmV35M0gOc54Jz/pcvkL)</kbd>.

Comment: disculpa que te moleste pero estuve probando por horas como agregar lo que tu me dijiste a la función que hice pero sigue sin salirme, no sé como hacer que tome los datos del vector en lugar de escribir n.insert({"ana", 0});

Comment: El ejemplo que compartí usa mapas, no vectores; si estás tratando de usar `insert` en un vector, fallará.